# Rails loop formatting how to put 'and' after the second last word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to but and just after the second loop.

Example I have:

```
<% kon.tags.each do |d| %>
<%= link_to d.name, tag_path(d.kategori.slug, d.slug) %>,
<% end %>
```

It outputs: `link, link, link, link,`

What I want is: `link, link, link and link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provides a helper for this ([Array#to_sentence](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence)), so you can do:

```
<%= raw kon.tags.collect { |d| link_to d.name, tag_path(d.kategori.slug, d.slug) }.to_sentence %>
```

Although be careful if you're using raw for user input.